# JQuery Mobile 1.4 - data-theme only partly applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themes

I need to upgrade to JQM 1.4 and can't seem to figure out this new dialog stuff. I used JQM 1.3 before without any problems.

I inject a <span> element on the main page with html code and then "enhance" it. The code represents a dialog that floats above the screen.

```
<span id='dialog'></span>

$.ajax(
{
  url: '/web/dialogs/' + dlg.page + '.aspx',
  success: function (content)
  {
    $('#dialog').html(content).enhanceWithin();
    ...
  }
});
```

Content is this ...

```
<div data-role="dialog" data-dialog="true" data-overlay-theme="a" data-close-btn="right" style="display: inline">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Headertext</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" role="main" data-theme="a" class="ui-content">
    <table>... controls, stuff ...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the "dialog" appears and the **controls/widgets are enhanced**, but the theme is **not completely** applied.

**It is applied** to the header, the header-div (data-role="header") contains class="ui-header ui-bar-**a**". This part is correct.

**It is not applied** to the content, the content-div is missing class="... ui-overlay-**a**" and all inner input controls are also missing the ui-*-a classes. Making the dialog content background-transparent.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

I also don't understand the difference between "role" and "data-role". And "data-overlay-theme", "data-content-theme", "data-theme". The default value of the latter ones is "a" anyway so even if I missed one it wouldn't matter. Cannot be the problem.

I just want JQM 1.4 to add all theme classes (like ui-overlay-**a**, ui-btn-**a**) correctly in the content-div and some *secret/magic/blackbox thingy* is preventing it. Any idea?

Comment: Add data-theme to dialog not not only overlay.

Comment: can you create a fildde? I couldn't reproduce it on fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/M9dZZ/

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/dUtUf/

Comment: I have same problem. Any tips?